# When using a variable to set the path, I get "No such file or directory", but works fine otherwise

Tags: environment-variables

I set the variable `CATKIN_WS="~/catkin_ws"`, but when I use it, it does not work. However, if I simply go to the path that I have set it at, I have no problems. Why does it not work when I set it as a variable, but works otherwise?

```
(venv) cedric@ubuntu-cedric:~$ echo $CATKIN_WS
~/catkin_ws
(venv) cedric@ubuntu-cedric:~$ cd $CATKIN_WS
bash: cd: ~/catkin_ws: No such file or directory
(venv) cedric@ubuntu-cedric:~$ cd ~/catkin_ws/
(venv) cedric@ubuntu-cedric:~/catkin_ws$
```

Comment: Try `CATKIN_WS="$HOME/catkin_ws"`

Comment: That solved the issue for me, thank you!

Comment: @ajgringo619 I think having an answer about this would be useful; I suggest posting one. You did solve the problem for the OP, after all. I mentioned and linked to your comment in my answer, but my answer isn't about that and even recommends a different approach.

Comment: No biggie. It's working for the OP, that's all that matters.

Answer (score 4):

In the shell, even though [double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes) provide [a weaker form](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes#Types_of_quoting) of [quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting) than [single quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes), they still suppress [tilde expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Tilde-Expansion), which is what converts `~/catkin_ws` (in some contexts where it appears) into an actual path.

Because `catkin_ws` contains no characters treated specially by the shell, I suggest you simply omit the double quotes in that assignment, writing this instead:

```
CATKIN_WS=~/catkin_ws
```

(That works because after the `=` in a variable assignment, i.e. at the beginning of the value you assign to a variable, is one of the places where tilde expansion is performed. The others are after a `:` in the value you assign to a variable and, of course, at the very beginning of a word.)

But if you wanted to quote `catkin_ws` you could:

```
CATKIN_WS=~/'catkin_ws'
```

You can also use `$HOME` instead of `~` as [ajgringo619 suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1168678/when-using-a-variable-to-set-the-path-i-get-no-such-file-or-directory-but-wo#comment1949724_1168678), since even though tilde expansion is not performed instead double quotes, [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) is. So long as `HOME` is set, it will achieve the same thing. (If `HOME` is unset, which is weird and not likely something you want to attempt to handle, then different shells behave differently; `bash` looks in the database of users to figure out the correct home directory in this situation.) This is a common and reasonable alternative.

Note that, while an initial use of double quotes prevented the tilde expansion you wanted, they will not prevent the parameter expansion of `$CATKIN_WS` later. You *[should double-quote](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes#When_Should_You_Quote.3F) those expansions.* [If you don't quote them](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells), the expanded value is subject to [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) and [globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion), which you don't want here (and most often don't want, when you use parameter expansion).

*Further reading: [Why doesn't the tilde (~) expand inside double quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151850/why-doesnt-the-tilde-expand-inside-double-quotes)*

Answer (score 2):

From `man bash`:

```
EXPANSION
       Expansion  is performed on the command line after it has been split into words.  There are
       seven kinds of expansion performed: brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter and  vari‐
       able  expansion,  command substitution, arithmetic expansion, word splitting, and pathname
       expansion.

       The order of expansions is: brace  expansion;  tilde  expansion,  parameter  and  variable
       expansion,  arithmetic  expansion, and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fash‐
       ion); word splitting; and pathname expansion.
```

As you can see, the tilde expansion is performed before the variable expansion, so if you run `cd $CATKIN_WS`, the shell will try to find a directory named `~` which doesn't exist.